# Submit iOS Push Notification App to app store

Tags: ios, push-notification, submit, provisioning-profile

I made a simple push notification app and try to submit to app store.

I created two types certificates(iOS distribution and APNs Production iOS).

And I added the APNs Production Certificate to Production SSL certificate of existing my app id(com.push.app). The app id(com.push.app) already has Development SSL Certificate(APNs Development iOS).

And I created a provisioning profile with iOS distribution type certificate and used for build app.

I want to know that my procedure is right or wrong because normally we use APNs Development provisioning profile for develpoing as everybody knows.

Regards

Comment: I see no problem in your approach. It should work fine. Just verify that you generated distribution certificate with gateway.push.apple.com. Also its always wise to have different app id for developement/distribution locally and while launching app on Appstore.

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply and you think that I need to revoke development SSL from the app id ?

Comment: Indeed it is not required if not for release version on AppStore.

Comment: Thanks and can I have one more question ? Do I need to create the  APNs production provisioning profile to submit app to app store ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine. Just verify that you generated distribution certificate with gateway.push.apple.com. Also its always wise to have different app id for developement/distribution locally and while launching app on Appstore.

> Once you configure your app to use APNs, Xcode automatically creates
>   the necessary distribution provisioning profiles when you export your
>   iOS app for beta testing or submit your app to the store.

Please follow:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html

Comment: The link is dead: “The page you’re looking for can’t be found.”